# PostgreSQL: Extract specific information from json

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 and I have the following table, let's call it `table1`:

```
id  | json_data
____________________
200 | {"state": [3, 4, 5]}
```

I want to be able to perform the following query: extract the array inside the `"state"` key in `json_data` for the record with id `1`, but also remove some of the integers from the array in the process.

For example (in pseudo-code):

`extract_state(id = 200, remove_numbers_from_json_data_state = [3, 5])` should return `[4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use a query like this:

```
SELECT json_data->'state'->>1 FROM table1 WHERE id = 200;
```

You can test this way, without having a table:

```
SELECT '{"state": [3, 4, 5]}'::jsonb->'state'->>1
```

Here is a reference for using JSON in Postgres:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

It returns `4`, not `[4]`, so if you need to, you could select it as an array:

```
SELECT ARRAY[('{"state": [3, 4, 5]}'::jsonb->'state'->>1)::int]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function for that, but you can easily write your own:

```
create function remove_numbers(p_array jsonb, p_nr variadic int[] )
returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_agg(x)
  from jsonb_array_elements(p_array) as t(x)
  where t.x::int <> ALL(p_nr);
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select id, remove_numbers(json_data -> 'state', 4,5)
from t1
where id = 1;
```

If you prefer to pass a JSON array value, you can define the function like this:

```
create function remove_numbers(p_array jsonb, p_to_remove jsonb)
returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_agg(x)
  from jsonb_array_elements(p_array) as t(x)
  where t.x not in (select *
                    from jsonb_array_elements(p_to_remove))
$$
language sql;
```

Then you would need to use `remove_numbers(json_data -> 'state', '[4,5]')`